# HttpClient PostAsync C# always return 404 Not Found on consuming web api

Tags: c#, node.js, rest, express, httpclient

I have a server-code on nodejs with express, that service works fine on test with Postman

Server-code:

```
app.post("/v2/addComment", (request, response) => {
   let n = parseInt(request.query.number);
   let key = request.get("key");
   let token = request.get("token");
   getToken(token).then(result => {   
      let kind = result[0].kind;
      if(kind === key){
         addComment(n, request.body);
         var success = { event : 'done' };
         return response.json(success);
      }
      else{
         var success1 = { event : 'not done' };
         return response.json(success1)
      }
   }).catch(error => console.log(error));
});
```

I'm try to consume this service from Windows Form app with HttpClient

```
private async Task<string> PostAsyncToken(string token, string key, int num, 
    List<Comment> comments){
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myhost.com/");
    string uri = string.Format("v2/addComment?number={0}", num);

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();    
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));                
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token", token);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", key);                              

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comments);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri,content);
    string contentResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return await Task.Run(() => contentResponse);   
}
```

Testing response always return 404 Not Found, and I guess it's because request adds automatically 'https' when it should be 'http' as working on Postman

Comment: "it's because request adds automatically 'https'" - why would it happen?

Comment: I'd use an inspection tool such as Fiddler to see the Postman request vs yours.

Comment: I don't know, but on debug I notice that ResponseUri of reponse shows `https://myhost.com/v2/addComment?number=1`